# How to send JWT header token and client data in POST request using axios

Tags: express, axios, jwt

I want to send a `JWT` token to `express` server with `axios` `POST` method.

What I have tried is:

```
let data = data
let head = {header: { Token: localStorage.getItem("token") }}
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3003/api/v/helllo", data, head)

  .then((result) => {
    console.table(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when working with `JWT` - `Authorization` header is used. Also pay attention that instead of `header` - `headers` field should be used:

```
let head = {
 headers: {
   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
 }
};
```

Beware, that storing tokens in local storage is not secure.

Comment: thank you the problem was with "header" after palcing "headers" it worked. Thanks your so... where should i store the token ???

Comment: We can also use cookies to store the tokens, I would say cookies are best place to store session data as local storage will not be deleted even after the session expires